# Multiple submenus but only one open at a time

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to make a navbar with links but within some links there are sub menus. So my road block starts at trying to write functional JS that allows only one sub menu open at a time and also close any sub menu that is open when a click occurs outside of the sub menu or the parent link.
Below is some of the code I am using (or trying to use). If anyone could provide some feed back to help me come up with a solution I would greatly appreciate it, Thanks!

Below is some of the JS I am using to grab the link and bind the lists with data toggles, I was thinking since there is already a click event that is targeting the lists maybe I could insert some logic in there to make it easier(?):

```js
const dataToggle = document.querySelectorAll("[data-toggle]");

for (var i = 0; dataToggle.length > i; i++) {
  let thisButton = dataToggle[i];
  let dataTarget = thisButton.getAttribute("data-target");
  let targetedItem = document.getElementById(dataTarget);

  let minusBtn = thisButton.querySelector(".navbar__menu-minus-svg");
  let plusBtn = thisButton.querySelector(".navbar__menu-plus-svg");

  thisButton.addEventListener("click", () => {
    console.log(thisButton);
    console.log(targetedItem);

    if (targetedItem.classList.contains("navbar__sub-menu-toggle-show")) {
      targetedItem.classList.remove("navbar__sub-menu-toggle-show");
      targetedItem.setAttribute("aria-expanded", "false");
      minusBtn.style.display = "none";
      plusBtn.style.display = "block";
    } else {
      targetedItem.classList.add("navbar__sub-menu-toggle-show");
      targetedItem.setAttribute("aria-expanded", "true");
      minusBtn.style.display = "block";
      plusBtn.style.display = "none";
    }
  });
}
```

```css
.menuLink {
  position: absolute;
  right: 20px;
  bottom: 40px;
}

.navbar__menu-list {
  width: 100%;
  display: none !important;
  list-style-type: none;
  background-color: #fff;
  padding: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 235px;
  border-top: 5px solid #1b75d5;
  border-radius: 0 0 10px 10px;
  font-size: 1.25rem;
}

.navbar__menu-list li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
}

.navbar__menu-list li a:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
  color: #1b75d5;
}

.navbar__menu-toggle-show {
  display: block !important;
}

.navbar__sub-menu-toggle-show {
  display: block;
}

.navbar__sub-menu-toggle-no-show {
  display: none !important;
}

header .container .mainNav .navbar__menu-list .navbar__has-sub-menu>ul {
  /* background-color: black; */
  /* display: block; */
}

.navbar__menu-list li {
  padding: 10px 15px;
}

.navbar__menu-list-item {
  padding: 5px 0;
}

.navbar__menu-list-item-link,
.navbar__sub-menu-list-item-link {
  color: #6d6d6d !important;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: flex !important;
  justify-content: space-between;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.navbar__menu-list-item-link:hover,
.navbar__menu-list-item-link:focus,
.navbar__sub-menu-list-item-link:hover,
.navbar__sub-menu-list-item-link:focus {
  text-decoration: underline !important;
  color: #1b75d5 !important;
}

.navbar__menu-list .navbar__menu-list-item:last-child a {
  border: none;
}

.navbar__sub-menu-list {
  display: none;
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-size: 0.875rem;
  padding-left: 3px;
}

ul.navbar__menu-list li ul {
  display: none;
  width: auto;
  background: #fff;
  border-bottom: 3px solid #cbcbcb;
  border-radius: 0 0 10px 10px;
  padding: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
}

.navbar__sub-menu-toggle-show {
  display: block !important;
}

.navbar__sub-menu-list-item-link {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #1b75d5;
}

.navbar__menu-plus-button,
.navbar__menu-minus-button {
  border: none;
  background-color: transparent;
}

.navbar__menu-plus-svg,
.navbar__menu-minus-svg {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
}

.navbar__menu-minus-svg {
  display: none;
}

@media (min-width: 1024px) {
  .menuLink {
    display: none;
  }
  .navbar__menu-list {
    position: static;
    display: flex !important;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    border: none;
    margin: 1em 0;
  }
  .navbar__menu-list-item {
    padding: 0 20px;
    position: relative;
  }
  .navbar__menu-svg-container {
    display: none;
  }
  .navbar__sub-menu-list::before {
    left: 25px;
  }
  ul.navbar__menu-list li ul {
    position: absolute;
    top: 70px;
    /* width: 90px; */
    border-top: 3px solid #1b75d5;
    left: 0;
    padding: 10px;
    font-size: 0.875rem;
  }
  ul.navbar__menu-list li ul::before {
    content: " ";
    position: absolute;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    top: -10px;
    left: 23px;
    margin-left: -10px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 0 10px 10px 10px;
    border-color: transparent transparent #1b75d5 transparent;
  }
  .navbar__sub-menu-list-item {
    width: 100%;
  }
  .navbar__sub-menu-list-item-link {
    border: none;
    padding: 2px 0;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 1440px) {
  .mainNav {
    display: flex;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 1920px) {
  .navbar__menu-list {
    width: 85%;
    justify-content: flex-end;
    font-size: 1.125rem;
    margin: 0 10px 0 0;
  }
  .navbar__menu-list-item {
    padding: 0 25px;
  }
  ul.navbar__menu-list li ul {
    top: 59px;
    width: auto;
    left: 10px;
    padding: 14px 8px;
    font-size: 1rem;
  }
  .navbar__sub-menu-list-item-link {
    padding: 4px 2px;
  }
}
```

```html
<nav class="mainNav clearfix">
  <div class="sitelogo__container">
    <a class="sitelogo" href="#">
      <img src="../cms/Assets/Logo Default.png" class="navbar__logo" alt="logo" />
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="menuLink icon-list">
    <span class="visuallyHidden">Menu</span>
    <svg class="icon icon-bars menu__toggle-svg">
      <use xlink:href="#icon-bars"></use>
    </svg>
  </div>
  <ul class="navbar__menu-list">
    <li class="navbar__menu-list-item">
      <a class="navbar__menu-list-item-link" data-toggle data-target="list-1">About Us
        <div class="navbar__menu-svg-container">
          <svg class="icon icon-plus  navbar__menu-plus-svg"><use xlink:href="#icon-plus"></use></svg>
          <svg class="icon icon-minus navbar__menu-minus-svg"><use xlink:href="#icon-minus"></use></svg>
        </div>
      </a>
      <ul class="navbar__sub-menu-list" id="list-1">
        <li class="navbar__sub-menu-list-item">
          <a class="navbar__sub-menu-list-item-link" href="#">Our History</a>
        </li>
        <li class="navbar__sub-menu-list-item">
          <a class="navbar__sub-menu-list-item-link" href="#">Our Staff</a>
        </li>
        <li class="navbar__sub-menu-list-item">
          <a class="navbar__sub-menu-list-item-link" href="#">Our Boards</a>
        </li>
        <li class="navbar__sub-menu-list-item">
          <a class="navbar__sub-menu-list-item-link" href="#">Our Bylaws</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="navbar__menu-list-item">
      <a class="navbar__menu-list-item-link" data-toggle data-target="list-2">Vendor Partners</a>
      <ul class="navbar__sub-menu-list" id="list-2">
        <li class="navbar__sub-menu-list-item">
          <a class="navbar__sub-menu-list-item-link" href="#">Our History</a>
        </li>
        <li class="navbar__sub-menu-list-item">
          <a class="navbar__sub-menu-list-item-link" href="#">Our Staff</a>
        </li>
        <li class="navbar__sub-menu-list-item">
          <a class="navbar__sub-menu-list-item-link" href="#">Our Boards</a>
        </li>
        <li class="navbar__sub-menu-list-item">
          <a class="navbar__sub-menu-list-item-link" href="#">Our Bylaws</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="navbar__menu-list-item">
      <a class="navbar__menu-list-item-link" data-toggle data-target="list-3">Membership Options & Benefits</a>
    </li>
    <li class="navbar__menu-list-item">
      <a class="navbar__menu-list-item-link" href="#">News & Resources</a>
      <ul class="navbar__sub-menu-list" id="list-3">
        <li class="navbar__sub-menu-list-item">
          <a class="navbar__sub-menu-list-item-link" href="#">Our History</a>
        </li>
        <li class="navbar__sub-menu-list-item">
          <a class="navbar__sub-menu-list-item-link" href="#">Our Staff</a>
        </li>
        <li class="navbar__sub-menu-list-item">
          <a class="navbar__sub-menu-list-item-link" href="#">Our Boards</a>
        </li>
        <li class="navbar__sub-menu-list-item">
          <a class="navbar__sub-menu-list-item-link" href="#">Our Bylaws</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="navbar__menu-list-item">
      <a class="navbar__menu-list-item-link" href="#">Contact Us</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: I made you a snippet. Please add relevant code to show a [mcve] - it is not currently possible the see the issue

Comment: This is a very common question, and while most answers that a search would turn up relate to jQuery, the solution concepts are similar. I suggest a search.

Comment: Just a guess: should this work? `let targetedItem = document.getElementById(dataTarget);` when you don't have an `id` on the html element? You may try to console.log this value `targetedItem` and see what's inside.

Comment: Apologies, I should've checked to see if this stuff was visible. Please give me a minute to make a proper mock up.

Comment: Also to answer Kurt's question, when I console log targetedItem, it gives me the list associated with the respective link. For example if I clicked on the second navbar link (Vendor Partners) the targetedItem is UL id="list-2". This is the reason I was thinking there has to be something to put into the JS since those lists are already being targeted. Maybe I'm wrong though

Comment: Ok, I set up a small demo of the stuff I'm having trouble with. I want the user to be able to only open one submenu at a time for both desk top and mobile. Also if a click occurs anyone other than the submenu of it's children the submenu should close. If anyone has any ideas I would greatly appreciate it

Comment: This is the link to a code pen I quickly threw together to show what I'm having trouble with: https://codepen.io/ray-hernandezAE/pen/mdqZxLz